# How to set ForeignKey column name in fluent API on EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to give my Foreign Key column the name I want.

If I set my foreignKey with the builder.Property, aka

```
var b = builder.Property(column.PropertyType, column.PropertyName);
b.ForSqlServerHasName("MyFKColumnName");
```

, when I create relationship, I have an error on migration : 
"The navigation property 'LettreClePrincipale' cannot be added to the entity type 'LettreCleAssociation' because a property with the same name already exists on entity type 'LettreCleAssociation'."

If I don't set my foreignKey with the builder.Property, this error is gone, the key is correctly created, but I cannot set name during the process :

```
ltcLinkBuilder.HasOne(typeof(LTC).FullName, "Link1")
.WithMany().IsRequired()
.HasForeignKey("Link1ID").OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
.???
```

I've defined my model like this (whit many more properties)

```
class LTC
        {
            public int TestA { get; set; }
            public string TestB { get; set; }

            public Guid Id { get; set; }

            protected ICollection<LTCLinks> _links { get; set; }

            public IReadOnlyList<LTCLinks> Links
            {
                get
                {
                    return _links.ToList().AsReadOnly();
                }
            }
        }

        class LTCLinks
        {
            public Guid Link1ID { get; set; }
            public LTC Link1 { get; set; }
            public Guid? Link2ID { get; set; }
            public LTC Link2 { get; set; }

            public string Data { get; set; }
        }
```

I don't have ForSqlServerHasName or ForSqliteHasName extensions method here. How can I proceed to achieve this ?

Running on EFCore 1.1 preview 1.

Comment: Show your entity classes please.

Comment: Very huge one in this case, I'll post a short version of it

Answer (score 1):

You have two relations between `LTC` and `LTCLinks` and I guess EF doen't know which one to use in `LTC.Links` collection... Check [InverseProperty](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#inverseproperty) attribute, you should have something like:

```
[InverseProperty("Link2")]
public IReadOnlyList<LTCLinks> Links {...}
```

About your original question, here is code that works:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int FooId { get; set; }

        public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; }

        public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test; Trusted_Connection=True");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>(t =>
            {
                t.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>(t =>
            {
                t.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                t.Property(x => x.FooId).HasColumnName("FooIdColumn");
                t.HasOne(x => x.Foo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId).HasConstraintName("MyFK");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With this in `project.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.0.1" },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": { "type": "build", "version": "1.0.0-preview3-final" },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": { "type": "build", "version": "1.1.0-preview1-final" },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0-preview1-final"
  },

  "tools": { "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final" },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
  }
```

After generating and running migration I have in SQL:

[image]

Comment: My mappings works great, I configure them more deeply than show in my question.
Initialiy, I was asking for COLUMN name, not CONSTRAINT name. You can see in your last picture that the columnName is FooId, not MyFK.
Moreover, cause everything is setting up by reflection, I cannot use DataAnnotation, that's why I was only talking about Fluent API

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was not careful enough when reading... Updated my answer: now it's about column name too. Now without attributes, only fluent api. Also, updated to EF `1.1.0-preview1`.

Comment: I don't know if it's linked, but if you read the beginning of my question, I was  telling that if I used .Property to define column name, I have an error when doing the relationship. Also, you use Generic version of Propery method, I can't do it because of reflection (too slow)